# troubled passing data from asynctask to fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask

I seek to receive data from AsyncTask inside a fragment. I'm aware to achieve this with activity but having difficulties in fragment.

GetResult class

```
public interface GetResult {

    void getData(ArrayList<String> result);

}
```

myFrag class

```
public class myFrag extends Fragment implements GetResult{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFrag_layout, container, false);
        Button myBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button1);

        myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                myAsync obj = new myAsync();
                obj.setListener(getActivity());

            }
        });

    }
}
```

myAsync class

```
public class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    GetResult interfaceObj = null;

    public void setListener( GetResult interfaceObj ) {
    this.interfaceObj =  interfaceObj;
    }
}
```

I'm having problem with obj.setListener(getActivity). It say The method setListener(GetResult) in the  type myAsync is not applicable for the arguments (FragmentActivity). Thanks in advance to everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't figured out wt the problem is but there is another way to do it. I'll just share it here.

1st the interface class GetResult.class is same

2nd Changes in the fragment class myFrag.class

```
public class myFrag extends Fragment{

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.myFrag_layout, container, false);
        Button myBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.Button1);

        myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {

                getLoc obj = new getLoc(getActivity(), new GetResultInterface() {

                @Override
                public void processFinish(ArrayList<String> result) {
                    // U can get the result here

                }

        obj.execute(url);

        });

    }
}
```

3rd In AsyncTask myAsync.class

```
public class myAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{
    Context context;
    GetResult interfaceObj = null;

    public myAsync(Context context, GetResultInterface interfaceObj) {
        this.context = context;
        this.interfaceObj = interfaceObj;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        interfaceObj.processFinish(result);
    }
}
```